# PHP preg_replace заменить GET параметр

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Так вот, у меня есть вот такой ЧПУ:

```
materials/mods/1.12/page/2
```

При нажатии на новую страницу я должен убрать page и сделать вот так:

```
materials/mods/1.12
```

И у меня существует код:

```
preg_replace('(/page/)[0-9]+','',$url)
```

Но он ничего не заменяет. Помогите ПЖ буду благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблон регулярного выражения должен быть записан между т.н. ограничителями шаблона:

```
$text = 'materials/mods/1.12/page/2';

$text = preg_replace('~/page/\d+~', '', $text);

echo $text;
```

---

[Демо PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff18b5382f9b4fed12243603b9416077e4e3505f)
[Демо PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/4IdGxy/1)

Comment: Спасибо помогло! Не думал что так быстро получу ответ. И чего же знак ~ означает я что то недопонял?

Comment: @WhiteWolf знак тильды `~` - это и есть ограничитель шаблона. Если мой ответ является решением вашего вопроса, отметьте его галкой.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо большое!